# What is the name of the Microsoft UI Automation API tester tool that Microsoft made?

Tags: microsoft-ui-automation

Windows has a [UI Automation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32), and there is a small tool written by Microsoft that allows one to test and verify that a UI automation server implementation is working correctly. Its UI resembles Regedit. I've forgotten the name of the tool. What is the tool called, and where can I get it?

Comment: There's "Inspect" from the Windows SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects or the more recent "Accessibility Insights for Windows" https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/windows/overview

Comment: That's the one! Thanks!